# Why is my JQuery function not triggered on a cloned element when the event becomes "true"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have been making this form that must enable the back-end user to create new questions for users to answer. The form is cloned and appended to a div (selector **#content**) successfully after the first **.on(click)** event, but it won't duplicate the form again if the cloned button is pressed. The **.on(change)** event applied to my drop-down selection does change the content of respective divs like it is supposed to, but only on the original form.

Here's the JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.addAnswer').on("click", function () {
    var idx = $('#mp div[name^="antwoord"]:last').index() + 1;
    $clone = $('#mp div[name^="antwoord"]:first').clone(true, true).attr('class', 'answer content_' + idx);
    $('.removeAnswer').show;
    $('#mp').append($clone);
    $('.answer:last').each(function () {
        $('b:last').empty();
        $('b:last').prepend(String.fromCharCode(64 + idx) + ". ")
        $('.addAnswer').on("click", function () {
            idx++;
        });
    });
    if (idx == 2) {
        $('.removeAnswer').show();
    }
});

$('.nextq').click(function () {
    var newqid = $('#content form:last').index() + 1;
    $('.done, .nextq, .remove').hide();
    $('#content').append('<hr>');
    $('#content').append($('form').html()).attr('class', 'q_' + newqid);
    $('.nextq').on("click", function () {
        newqid++;
    });
    $('.done:last, .nextq:last, .remove:last').show();
    return false;
});

$('.group').hide();
$('#text:last').show();
$('.select:last').on("change", function () {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val() + ':last').fadeIn();
    $('button.' + $(this).val() + ':last').fadeIn();
});
});
```

Because I thought posting the whole HTML template would be a tad bit too much, I provided a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dPk8N/) for you people.

One extra question for the ones that are feeling kind: In the JQuery code it is seen that the contents of the HTML are being parsed using **.html()** and appended with **.append**.(Line 33 on the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dPk8N/)) As the **.on(change)** function switches the contents of the divisions it should change, **.html()** sees those changes and takes those along with it. I'd like the **.on(click)** function to append the div's content in its original state, unchanged by the changes made beforehand by the back-end user. Any help with this would be much obliged.

Comment: You might try cloning the form on load instead of on click. Then u will have a copy of the original form u can append in the on click event.

Comment: So, how exactly should I do this? Do I just take the declared **$clone** object out of the function and put it on top of the code inside the **.ready()**? Me no comprende just yet!

Comment: Yes exactly, The only other thing you will have to do is clone that clone in your onclick event see fiddle example here. http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/8nM2a/

Comment: I have updated the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dPk8N/1/) and tried to do as you told me, but it's not working and it's frustrating the faeces out of me. The problem is that the duplicated textareas also show itself in the cloned element as the div inside **#mp** is cloned. Help!

Comment: i might be a little confused but here's another fiddle based on your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/GMpZs/1/  I had to change several things for it to work right.  And I'm cloning your entire form at the top. I hope this is what your looking for.

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for. Except now, the textareas cannot be cloned anymore. And the letters aren't appended correctly. The @ symbol doesn't come second in the alphabet, right?

Comment: Alright try this one http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/GMpZs/9/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have jQuery trigger on new elements you would do something like

```
$( document ).on( "click", "<your id or class>", function() {
  //Do stuff
});
```